# How to create a permission based views in extjs?

Tags: extjs

In my application, I want to show some widget based on user group authentication. I am creating one singleton class that will have some function to authenticate the different user groups. On the basis of Boolean value returned by the function I will show the widget to the user.My permission based view is(I would create a utility method that can be loaded):

```
Ext.define('MyApp.utility.Common', {
    singleton : true,
    //Here I will check weather current user is same as the user 
    //I want to show widget(I have acess to current user)
    getUser : function(user) {//if currentUser == user return true 
                              else    false...}
    //Here I will check weather user higher level person should see the 
    //the widget or not
    getOneLevelUPUser: function(user) {...}

});
```

At any point in my application I will access this function as: MyApp.utility.Common.getUser(user).

Is the above method correct to implement the permission based views? If not Can u suggest the best one

Comment: I think that's a pretty decent approach.